# Eclipse 2019-06 is freezes when I try to open run or debug configurations

Tags: eclipse

I have recently stated using Eclipse 2019-06 and I have most things working great, but I went to debug an application today and it just hangs before I can even get the run or debug configuration panel open. This works fine in a new 'empty' workspace but when I try it in my big workspace that has many launch configurations from prior versions of Eclipse (mostly Luna), no luck, I have to kill Eclipse at that point.

I do see a launch configuration "Migrate" button under Preferences/Run/Debug but it doesn't see my launch files or let me search for them.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully I figured this out pretty quickly. I had disabled CodeMix because it was a resource pig and not really helping me but I had created a CodeMix launch which once I removed, my problems went away.

Comment: Wayne - we're sorry to hear CodeMix caused performance problems for you. The good news is that we tracked these down and fixed them, so if you update to the most recent CodeMix release and enable it (if you ever need CodeMix), you should no longer experience performance problems. If interested, you can read more about it here: https://www.genuitec.com/codemix-2019-8-21-performance-update/

We're also going to take a look at your launch configuration experience when CodeMix was disabled, that shouldn't be happening.